# Worklist template i18n <ObjectName>

Tags: sapui5, sap-fiori, sap-web-ide, sap-business-application-studio

Does the `<ObjectName>` refer to a variable which contains the name of the object? Or should I replace it manually with a suitable name?

The IDE generated `#XTIT: Table view title worklistTableTitle=<ObjectName>` in i18n.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use SAP WebIDE to create a template/application, it may create i18n files with placeholders for you to replace them with your own application specific texts. In your case, in the code below **<ObjectName>** represents a placeholder for your own text.

```
#XTIT: Table view title 
worklistTableTitle=<ObjectName>
```

It does not refer to any variable, you simple have to add you own text in that field. Something similar to this :

```
#XTIT: Table view title 
worklistTableTitle=My Products List
```

Answer (score 3):

The line which you have mentioned

> `#XTIT: Table view title worklistTableTitle=<ObjectName>`

This is just a sort of comment in i18n file.

`appDescription=<you can fill anything you can here>` to reflect in your app.